# Is swapping with a default jthread allowed?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it allowed to call swap on `current`?
In the example [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/swap) both threads are running.

Full example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>


void play_stream(std::stop_token stoken, std::string stream_url)
{
    std::cout << "mediaplayer: start for " << stream_url << "\n";

    std::promise<void> stop;
    std::stop_callback callBack(stoken, [&stop] {
        stop.set_value();
    });

    // wait until canceled
    stop.get_future().wait();
}

int main(int /*ac*/, char** av)
{   
    std::jthread current;
    
    std::jthread play{play_stream, av[0]};
    current.swap(play);
}
```

Motivation for this question is if i do that inside Crow it starts to act [interesting](https://github.com/CrowCpp/Crow/issues/765).

Comment: [The standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.jthread.mem#1) does not mention any pre-condition, so why do you doubt?

Comment: @273K i did mention the motivation for asking this question at the end of the post 

Comment: Any feedback on why this is a bad question? From people who voted this question down?

Comment: The question must include the motivated code, not a link to that code. As seen below, the answer is completely irrelevant to the code in the question.

Comment: I mean that is now very philosophical, yes my issue was somewhere else but i fail to see how that makes this question which is more narrow in scope invalid or bad so what you argue is to ask more broad questions instead of multiple specific questions which i can't find in the recommendations on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To my point i would have accepted an answer which points to the standard and explains why this is valid as the correct answer. - And i fail to see how the motivating code for this part of the question is mission maybe it's an easy question for people familiar with the standard but i don't think thats the relevant if it is a good or bad question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your actual problem, you do not wait for the `std::string` to be constructed before you return.

A default constructed `jthread` is relatively quick to destroy, whereas the subsequent `jthread`s need to wait for `join()`.

This means the first time round, `data["url"].s()` (which returns a reference-like type) is destroyed and becomes dangling before the return (and seems to point to whatever that buffer was used for next). But the second time, the function has to wait for the old `jthread` (now swapped to be in `play`) to `join()`, so it has time to construct the `std::string` from `data["url"].s()`.

You have a race, where the easiest solution is to pass in a `std::string` already: `std::jthread play{play_stream, std::string{data["url"].s()}};`. This will mean that a `std::string` is passed to the new thread instead of a `crow::json::detail::r_string`, and there are no lifetime issues / races.

The `std::jthread` constructor's return is synchronized with the start of `std::invoke(auto(std::forward<Function>(f)), get_stop_token() auto(std::forward<Args>(args))...)` in the new thread. This means the first action taken is to construct the `std::string` in the body of `std::invoke` to pass to the function pointer, so you would have make sure `args...` is valid until that happens (by making it a `std::string` in the first place or some other method of synchronization)